# Problem With Jagged Edges When Using Boolean Difference

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers

When I go to use a *Boolean* modifier, some edges are jagged but the model doesn't seem like it would cause that.

[image: object and boolean object]

[image: object and boolean object]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably because you have four faces on your plane at the top, and only three on the object that you were trying to boolean difference with. It's like when you try to sharpen a regular eight-sided pencil. The edges are always jagged.

Comment: thanks! I have a problem thinking about it but I added another side and it fixed it right up :)